# After my husband wrote talaq three times, then said it three times, is our talaq valid?

Tags: talaq

My husband gave me all 3 talaq at once. He wrote on a page: talaq, talaq, talaq.

A week later a mufti said it was not valid. He then recited I divorce you, I divorce you, I divorce you. He now states he has made a huge mistake and wants to rectify this!

Is this at all possible? Or is our talaq permanent?

Comment: [Just reciting “Talak” thrice commits divorce?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/103/3487)

Answer (score 4):

There is no concept of saying talaq thrice at once in Islam. So saying it or writing it, does not fulfill the conditions of the talaq, which renders it invalid.

Comment: @Nadia Upvote and accept(the clicking tick below the down arrow, to the left of your comment above) is probably the best form of appreciation.