# Can a man marry his ex wife two years after divorce?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, talaq

Can a man marry his ex wife two years after divorce? What is the ruling of Islam about this according shari'a.

Comment: have not you tried to search "islam divorce" in some search engine?

Comment: Please consider adding information. For example what kind of talaq was it. As only in case of talaq rij'i remarrying would be allowed. Generally this is an easy googlable question.

Comment: duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/is-it-possible-to-remarry-my-husband-after-being-divorced-years-ago

Answer (score 1):

If it was the third divorce then the couple can not remarry unless the woman marries another man and is genuinely divorced or widowed in the second marriage, and no passage of time will make them lawful otherwise.

> [Quran 2:230](https://quran.com/2/230) And if he has divorced her [for the third time], then
>   she is not lawful to him afterward until [after] she marries a husband
>   other than him. And if the latter husband divorces her [or dies],
>   there is no blame upon the woman and her former husband for returning
>   to each other if they think that they can keep [within] the limits of
>   Allah . These are the limits of Allah, which He makes clear to a
>   people who know.

If it was the second or first divorce then they can remarry:

> [Quran 2:229](https://quran.com/2/229) Divorce is twice. Then, either keep [her] in an
>   acceptable manner or release [her] with good treatment. And it is not
>   lawful for you to take anything of what you have given them unless
>   both fear that they will not be able to keep [within] the limits of
>   Allah . But if you fear that they will not keep [within] the limits of
>   Allah, then there is no blame upon either of them concerning that by
>   which she ransoms herself. These are the limits of Allah, so do not
>   transgress them. And whoever transgresses the limits of Allah - it is
>   those who are the wrongdoers.
>
> [Quran 65:2](https://quran.com/65/2) And when they have [nearly] fulfilled their term,
>   either retain them according to acceptable terms or part with them
>   according to acceptable terms. And bring to witness two just men from
>   among you and establish the testimony for [the acceptance of] Allah .
>   That is instructed to whoever should believe in Allah and the Last
>   day. And whoever fears Allah - He will make for him a way out.

Answer (score -2):

To marry an ex-wife, there are some conditions. After your divorce  she should be married to another and he have to have sex with her and then he should divorce her and after Idha of 3 months u can marry your ex-wife.

Comment: He has to divorce but if the marriage is decided to be limited time, it is not valid. So it s supposed to be a normal marriage until they decided to divorce or the husband dies. I mean divorce reason shouldnt be to let the previous husband marry again