# How does triple talaq work in conjunction with court?

Tags: talaq

I have heard that in Islam three divorce are given with the interval of a month. And of divorce in iddah if they change their mind they can get together.

And girl get notice through court how does she know that she get three divorce or not?
If Islam give us right to give divorce in interval of a month then how is possible through court?

*Please explain through Quran.*

Comment: more early question about triple divorce: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/103/

Comment: "I have heard that in Islam three divorce are given with the interval of a month. And of divorce in iddah if they change their mind they can get together." - they are 2 different things. so, question is not very clear. and question about court is 3rd thing.

Comment: i have found solution for triple divorce problem, and i want to write it to the question number 103, because it is more early, though it is also not clear question. i want to write a new correct/clear question just for the triple talaq problem, but i do not want to make one more duplicate. if the 103th question should be used for the problem, this question has only court problem left, i think it is not a problem, if the triple divorce problem is solved. so, i think, this question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: " ... in Islam three divorce are given with the interval of a month." This statement is factually incorrect. Each divorce has iddah which needs to be passed. It differs based on whether the lady is a virgin or has had relationship with her present husband or is now a widow.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your inquiry that inquired concerning explanation of divorce in the holy Qur’an, I can present here in regard to some verses of the holy Quran which are related to the issue of the talaq which probably could be beneficial for you.

> لِّلَّذِينَ يُؤْلُونَ مِن نِّسَائِهِمْ تَرَبُّصُ أَرْبَعَةِ أَشْهُرٍ ۖ
>   فَإِن فَاءُوا فَإِنَّ اللَّـهَ غَفُورٌ رَّحِيمٌ ﴿٢٢٦﴾ وَإِنْ عَزَمُوا
>   الطَّلَاقَ فَإِنَّ اللَّـهَ سَمِيعٌ عَلِيمٌ ﴿٢٢٧﴾ وَالْمُطَلَّقَاتُ
>   يَتَرَبَّصْنَ بِأَنفُسِهِنَّ ثَلَاثَةَ قُرُوءٍ ۚ وَلَا يَحِلُّ لَهُنَّ
>   أَن يَكْتُمْنَ مَا خَلَقَ اللَّـهُ فِي أَرْحَامِهِنَّ إِن كُنَّ
>   يُؤْمِنَّ بِاللَّـهِ وَالْيَوْمِ الْآخِرِ ۚ وَبُعُولَتُهُنَّ أَحَقُّ
>   بِرَدِّهِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ إِنْ أَرَادُوا إِصْلَاحًا ۚ وَلَهُنَّ مِثْلُ
>   الَّذِي عَلَيْهِنَّ بِالْمَعْرُوفِ ۚ وَلِلرِّجَالِ عَلَيْهِنَّ
>   دَرَجَةٌ ۗ وَاللَّـهُ عَزِيزٌ حَكِيمٌ ﴿٢٢٨﴾
>
> For those who swear not to have sexual relations with their wives is a
>   waiting time of four months, but if they return [to normal relations]
>   - then indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. (226) And if they decide on divorce - then indeed, Allah is Hearing and Knowing. (227)
>   Divorced women remain in waiting for three periods, and it is not
>   lawful for them to conceal what Allah has created in their wombs if
>   they believe in Allah and the Last Day. And their husbands have more
>   right to take them back in this [period] if they want reconciliation.
>   And due to the wives is similar to what is expected of them, according
>   to what is reasonable. But the men have a degree over them [in
>   responsibility and authority]. And Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise.
>   (228)
>
> (Al-Baqarah: 226,227,228)

Or for instance Al-Baqarah: 229.

> الطَّلَاقُ مَرَّتَانِ ۖ فَإِمْسَاكٌ بِمَعْرُوفٍ أَوْ تَسْرِيحٌ
>   بِإِحْسَانٍ ۗ وَلَا يَحِلُّ لَكُمْ أَن تَأْخُذُوا مِمَّا
>   آتَيْتُمُوهُنَّ شَيْئًا إِلَّا أَن يَخَافَا أَلَّا يُقِيمَا حُدُودَ
>   اللَّـهِ ۖ فَإِنْ خِفْتُمْ أَلَّا يُقِيمَا حُدُودَ اللَّـهِ فَلَا
>   جُنَاحَ عَلَيْهِمَا فِيمَا افْتَدَتْ بِهِ ۗ تِلْكَ حُدُودُ اللَّـهِ
>   فَلَا تَعْتَدُوهَا ۚ وَمَن يَتَعَدَّ حُدُودَ اللَّـهِ فَأُولَـٰئِكَ
>   هُمُ الظَّالِمُونَ ﴿٢٢٩﴾
>
> Divorce is twice. Then, either keep [her] in an acceptable manner or
>   release [her] with good treatment. And it is not lawful for you to
>   take anything of what you have given them unless both fear that they
>   will not be able to keep [within] the limits of Allah. But if you fear
>   that they will not keep [within] the limits of Allah, then there is no
>   blame upon either of them concerning that by which she ransoms
>   herself. These are the limits of Allah, so do not transgress them. And
>   whoever transgresses the limits of Allah - it is those who are the
>   wrongdoers. (229)

Or according to the 230th verse of Surah Al-Baqarah:

> فَإِن طَلَّقَهَا فَلَا تَحِلُّ لَهُ مِن بَعْدُ حَتَّىٰ تَنكِحَ زَوْجًا
>   غَيْرَهُ ۗ فَإِن طَلَّقَهَا فَلَا جُنَاحَ عَلَيْهِمَا أَن يَتَرَاجَعَا
>   إِن ظَنَّا أَن يُقِيمَا حُدُودَ اللَّـهِ ۗ وَتِلْكَ حُدُودُ اللَّـهِ
>   (يُبَيِّنُهَا لِقَوْمٍ يَعْلَمُونَ ﴿٢٣٠
>
> And if he has divorced her [for the third time], then she is not
>   lawful to him afterward until [after] she marries a husband other than
>   him. And if the latter husband divorces her [or dies], there is no
>   blame upon the woman and her former husband for returning to each
>   other if they think that they can keep [within] the limits of Allah.
>   These are the limits of Allah, which He makes clear to a people who
>   know. (230)

---

**Reference:**

- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/2:228)

Comment: Try highlighting and explaining. [Do evidences speak for themselves?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/do-evidences-speak-for-themselves)

Comment: yes please explain...

Answer (score -1):

> *Please explain through Quran.*

see my answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/32792 . and i have explained it through quran.

> I have heard that in Islam three divorce are given with the interval of a month.

you can see from my answer 32792 that this is not correct. you say about divorce that should be counted, when it is counted till 3. 1 month is interval invented by some scholars to solve triple talaq problem, but that is incorrect solution. divorce is counted after iddah is fullfilled.

> And of divorce in iddah if they change their mind they can get together.

this is true, and husband can easily take his wife back within iddah (waiting term of 3 periods...).

> And girl get notice through court how does she know that she get three divorce or not?

quran does not set court as requirement, but, as you can see in quran 65:2, after iddah is fullfilled, 2 witnesses should witness that divorce is accomplished and one more divorce is counted. as soon as you are fully divorced (fully means with iddah passed) 3 times without you marrying other men after that divorces, (and this means that you are like remarried same man 2 times, after 1st and after 2nd divorce), you cannot remarry same man, before you marry other man and divorce. and for example, if anybody lies that you are not yet divorced 3 times, you can go to court with your witnesses of the 3 divorces and proof that you are divorced 3 times.

> If Islam give us right to give divorce in interval of a month then how is possible through court?

as i said, islam does not give right to divorce after 1 month, but after iddah, and court can defend you even after 1 divorce (with iddah and 2 witnesses), if your ex-husband tries to to lie saying that iddah has not passed and take you back without your agreement. but you should have reliable, trustworthy witnesses. maybe in some countries divorce is witnessed and also additionally written in documents of special governmental divorce registration bureau, and maybe that document also can help you in court.

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting question and many people get confused on the subject. I highly recommend Mawdudi's lengthy discussion on Surah At-Talaq which can be read online at the following link and will provide you with a sound outline regarding the rules surrounding Islamic divorce: http://www.englishtafsir.com/Quran/65/index.html