# Can a woman marry another man after one divorce

Tags: nikah, talaq

If a man gives only one divorce to woman, can she marry someone else?
Or she has to wait for 3 divorces before marrying someone else?

Comment: In short, yes but she has to wait for her idah to complete. So no marriage in first 3 months of her divorce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One divorce is still a divorce.  Assuming she has gone through her *iddah* period, then yes, she is free to marry another.

The only difference between one divorce and three divorces is that three divorces is considered *irrevokable*; with one divorce, the couple still has the right to reconcile before the *iddah* has ended and retain their marriage.

For further details, check out my answer to the related question here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/113/22

Comment: one correction, note the couple but `the man` has the right to reconciliate or take her back. The woman can only wish, he would take her back.