# If my husband was unaware of the consequences of three talaqs, is still valid?

Tags: talaq

My husband is a revert and he gave me three talaqs, but he wasn't really sure of what he was doing because he thinks we can reconcile even if he give me three talaqs.  So if he was unaware of what he was really doing, is the talaq still valid?

Comment: Assalamualaikum,

May Allah help with your situation. Sister, with all due respect, the situation isn't something that could be asked here, find a scholar and get with him.This is your life.

Comment: probably duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce - that is about 3 "talaq"s at once; because real 3 divorces with reconcilings and not knowing about that 3rd reconciling is not possible is unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

my answer here was incorrect. i am going to write new answer in [Just reciting "Talak" thrice commits divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/103)

Comment: see http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce

Comment: You Think!! It doesn't matter what you think, it matters what sharia is say. In my idea rule of 3 divorce is also bullshit but what does matter is sharia rules...