# Is a divorce valid if the husband unintentionally says "okay" at his wife's request?

Tags: talaq

If husband and wife are fighting and wife ask for divorce but the husband has no intention to give divorce and remains silent, then the wife again says I can't live with you and husband unintentionally says
okay, but has no intention of divorce at all.  Now his wife says to him as you said "okay" to my statement, so the marriage is over.

Is it a valid divorce even if the husband did not utter anything except okay?

Comment: If the intention was not a divorce then it is not a divorce

Comment: "I can't live with u" is not exactly equal to "I will be divorced from you", and even if it was so, "ok" is not enough, but husband should wait iddah time without changing his mind about the divorce. only then, after iddah, 1 divorce is counted. see proof in my answer http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce/32792#32792 .

Answer (score 1):

No its not divorce is not something you just said and it happened. There is a way or giving divorce and there are steps that a muslim have to go through and if you didn't intend to say it or didn't mean it then no its not divorce.