# If my husband divorced me twice but says he did it three times, are we still married?

Tags: nikah, talaq

My husband divorced me twice, but he says that he did it three times. He only said it twice to me. Am I still married?

When he divorced me the first time we never separated, the second time again we never separated and we had intercourse in the same week.  I never wanted to divorce him.  And we have a son.

Comment: Maybe he divorced you twice but is not interested or doesn't intend (in) a turning back, so if you want to keep him you may need to find an intermediate ... Also if you had intercourse before the talaq isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

1. After uttering talaq if he has intercourse with you within 3 menstrual cycles it's counted as one.
2. He can take you back twice without a new contract if it's within 3 menustrual cycle period.
3. If uttered for 3rd time you cannot remarry/stay with the same person.
4. Divorce uttered for wrong reasons doesn't count.

https://islamqa.info/en/182868

Comment: you have a problem with this theory, in items 2 and 3: with this theory, it is possible to divorce and take back 2 times and divorce 3rd time even within a day, and even within a hour. that does not sound good, there is no conrcete limit of shortness of time, and it contradicts 2:228 where it is said "Divorced women remain in waiting for three periods", with this theory she may lose that right.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/106285 please go through that link. Further I firmly believe zaid bin harith said divorce only once to Zainab. Zainab observed iddat and married prophet. Waiting period is for those who intend not to return or under irrevocable divorce

Comment: islamqa.info/en/106285 does not solve the problem i shown

Comment: Why do you need 3 in a day ? When you can get irrevocably divorced by uttering once.

Comment: "When you can get irrevocably divorced by uttering once" - on what is this idea based?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/70224, zaid bin harith divorced Zainab on one uttering.

Comment: islamqa.info/en/70224 clearly says "once ... but it will be a revocable divorce", in 1st paragraph. the story of zaid probably was also so.

Comment: When you don't intend to return like Zainab it can be treated as irrevocably divorced in one uttering.

Comment: Not teturn like Zainab should be read as not intending to Take back like zaid

Comment: then also, whether husband wants to take his wife back or not does not change the state of the divorce mechanism itself. he may have no intention, but still will have right to remarry her if she can and agree, and that is revocability. and you cannot predict future, maybe he will change his mind and use his right.

Comment: If wife doesn't want to return after iddat, husband can't take her back even with a new contract and dower.

Comment: i said incorrectly "her divorce is always irrevocable", i delete that comment.

Answer (score 0):

The divorce is not a divorce, until the woman is informed clearly about it.
so he divorced you three times, you were informed twice, it counts just two.
and having intercourse is just a cancel for the divorce. so basically you're still married.

but i advice you to solve your problems, because he seems loving you deeply(returning back to you very quickly) , seeing a relationship therapist will help you two understand how to find a solutions to your problems without threating  or throwing talaq every-time,

Answer (score 0):

Sad story, sorry to read  it,  I wonder how many on this forum may agree   that once a man has made up his mind to divorce his wife in favour of his new prospective wife due to whatever reasons, it is a matter of time either few days or a few months he might break of the marital relations regardless of the laws

Laws are one thing and how the laws are interpreted and what strategy the lawyers use in presenting the case on behalf of their clients(money) and what sort of conviction a judge is going to give based on the presentation of the case is complex.

For instance in India many criminals get away from the clutches of the law if they can afford the most cunning lawyers and 60% of the so called law makers of India have themselves criminal record(as  per the election commission of India)

Laws on divorce may or may not allow Triple Talaq based on the rational interpretations of the Quran and hadith traditions and the  laws by the Indian Government or the Indian Ummah based Islamic Courts or bodies may prevent triple Talaq

But the greater issue is once a married couple ( husband or wife) have started hating each other, suspicious of each other’s honesty and chastity and have made up their minds to break off  relations no matter what, then the law preventing Triple Talaq and forcing them to give a gap of say three months or so may not work effectively in most of the cases.

Preventing instant Talaq may be a stop gap temporary measure and the long lasting solution is firmer Eeman, stronger taqwa and the fear that in Islam divorce is the one thing that Allah has allowed but the same thing that  shakes Allahs Arsh(power)

By nature and disposition we come across people  both men and women falling into  many categories, some are tough, jealous, oppressive, insecure and some are even adulterous and such  issues grow into irreconciliable differences and lead to a quick or delayed divorce

Answer (score -2):

i think you are not divorced even once, because only full divorce is counted for the 3 divorces rule. see more at [Just reciting "Talak" thrice commits divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce/32792#32792) .