# Does unwillingly saying "talaaq" three times count as divorce?

Tags: talaq

One of my friend's family forced him to say talaaq to his wife and unwillingly he said three talaaq at a time, but he never wanted to leave his wife as he loves her true heartedly.

Can this be considered as divorced as he said it unwillingly with force and threat?

Please advise as per Quraan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Just reciting "Talak" thrice commits divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce)

Comment: Forced actions are invalid by shari'a. I don't see how the proposed duplicate post addresss this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Talaq(divorce) has certain condition that needs to be met for it to be valid.

As Referred in the comment, Allah says in the Quran([2:228](https://quran.com/2/228) and [2:229](https://quran.com/2/229)), One of the condition for Divorce is that

> **Divorced women remain in waiting for three periods**, and it is not lawful for them to conceal what Allah has created in their wombs if they believe in Allah and the Last Day. And **their husbands have more right to take them back in this [period] if they want reconciliation**.

which didn't happen in your friend's case between two Talaq. So it is not valid. There are other condition as well which voids this Divorce. But since it was already been detailed in the link provided by Rebecca and ([here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce)). I have just listed one of those condition.If necessary I will append my answers.

The answer is NO. It is not valid.

Comment: This accepted answer doesn't even address the actual question at all. Forcing somebody to do something invalidates the action, so they never divorced in front of Allah. As the husband never intended to do it.

Comment: Asalam Alaikum all I spoke to many maulvis regarding this and all said divorced has taken place and they are no more in nikah now but the couple loves each other so much the man's family forced him to leave his wife as she is physically disabled and all relatives will laugh on them if they come to know about the marriage. Husband doesnt have any problem with his wife he accepted her with all love vut couldnt convince family and due to parents threat of suicide they both decided to show the family as they are seperated and decided to sign on papers but on the day of signing khazi forced husband

Comment: Forced husband to say talaq thrice for which both were not agreed but on khazi's force and parents threat husband unwillingly told talaq thrice but they both are still continuing the relation as in nikah and want to plan a baby now. I want to know is the divorce valid if someone threats a husbnd to tell talaq thrice where husband never wants to leave his wife bt due to threat tells the word talaq thrice.

Comment: @user22621 this is a new question which should be asked using te "ask question" link you can refer to this post there, but asking questions in the comment area is not recommended as sooner or later the cleaning-actions of mods may delete them!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks for bringing this up. But not sure what made you to downvote, which clearly shows you haven't read the Original Question and its revisions. OP specifically asks about "triple Talaq" in the subject "Three times talaaq in islam" was the original subject. I agree that it asks more about forced divorce. But my answer addresses the subject.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Moreover, the OP accepted the answer, which means my understanding of his/her intended question is right. 

If you look at your response, it doesn't either satisfies the Question. OP specifically asks for "referring to Quran". But you haven't mentioned any in your comments. Anyway, I am here with a good intention. If this is for a closed group or such, I am out of this.

جزاك اللهُ خيرًا