# If nikkah was broken due to uttering words of disbelief, then talaaq is given, does the talaaq count?

Tags: talaq

If a nikkah is broken first (in this case due to kalima kufr) then afterwards talaaq is given, does this talaaq count?

Kalima kufr is when someone utters words of disbelief.

Comment: Is this the woman's first marriage or was she married before?

Comment: It was her first marriage, she's only been married once and hasn't married since

Comment: What is the period of time between talaq to fast forward today?

Comment: See: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/103/just-reciting-talak-thrice-commits-divorce

Comment: What do you mean by kalima kufr?

Comment: Kalima kufr is when someone utters words of disbelief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the Nikah is broken due to Kalima Kufr, then the Talaaq doesn't count because Talaaq can be only be given when a Woman is in the Nikah of a Person.

Talaaq is defined by a renowned Book in Fiqh (Kanz ud Daqaiq):

> **هُوَ رَفْعُ الْقَيْدِ الثَّابِتِ شَرْعًا بِالنِّكَاحِ**
>
> Translation: **(Talaaq) is lifting up of the condition, which is imposed due to Nikah.**

So if the Nikah is already broken, then you can not give divorce to a woman. It's like giving divorce to an unknown woman.

Comment: Really good answer but would you have any more proofs / references?