# If a non-Muslim performs salah (prayers), does he become a Muslim?

Tags: salat, non-muslim, conversion, shahada, tashahhud

Suppose a person, who believes in one god, starts doing salah (prayers) as he loves Allah and his messenger and trusts them, but he does not accept Islam because of family and social problems. He does salah, pays zakkah, and does not break the rules which Allah has given to his messengers.

**Question:** When he prays 5 times a day, he reads the shahadah after wudu and in tashahud as we all do. Has he become a Muslim by reading shahadah even though he does not want to accept Islam?

Comment: This sounds confusing to me, however I think I got your issue. But I wonder if this is a kind of question that is answerable here. It looks to me like one that needs a specialist (fatwa).

Comment: What do you mean do not accept Islam? Every Muslim Must Follow Islam thats why he is a muslim.
Saying that he don't disclose his religion that is some think one can argue about. but if one's a muslim and he really love Allah (S.W.T) and His Prophet (P.B.U.H) then he should accept Islam

Comment: @Medi1Saif It reminds me of the discussion between ibn Hanbal and ash-Shafii about whether or not abandoning prayer makes one a kafir, maybe that'll be an interesting reference here? I don't know where to find that though.

Comment: @G.Bach in one of my answers I pointed at that, but the strange is that a-Shafi'i there defended an opinion which he is not 100% holding himself. But OP starts by saying a kafir is praying... that's the point which makes me a bit confused.

Comment: @G.Bach, the discussion between Ibn Hanbal and Ash-Shafi'i about one who abandons prayers is not authentic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the described situation, the person has performed all the physical actions required to become a Muslim.  Another Muslim would ordinarily accept this person as a Muslim.  Beyond that, it's impossible to be sure; it depends on the individuals heart, and is up to Allah.

It is plausible that not wanting to accept Islam (depending on what that means) is sufficient for that person to not have converted; it goes against:

> That is because they disliked what Allah revealed, so He rendered worthless their deeds.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 4:9](https://quran.com/47/9)</sub>

[SunnahOnline](http://sunnahonline.com/library/beliefs-and-methodology/87-types-of-kufr-disbelief) ("Adapted from Tafsir Ibn Kathir") describes this as a kind of [kufr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kafir) (disbelief) called *Kufr ul-Kurh* (*Disbelief out of detesting any of Allah's Commands*).

Also note that there are different kinds of followers of Islam, and this may be applicable here too:

> The bedouins say, "We have believed." Say, "You have not [yet] believed; but say [instead], 'We have submitted,' for faith has not yet entered your hearts. And if you obey Allah and His Messenger, He will not deprive you from your deeds of anything. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful."
>   <sub>[Qur'an 49:14](https://quran.com/49/14)</sub>

See also: [What is a "Muslim" (surrendered) and what is a "Mumin" (believer/safe)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18/17163)

Answer (score 0):

brother, Islam is an agreement between you and Allah. your family has nothing to do with it. if you do all of what you said and believe in them for real and the way you described them, then you are already a full time Muslim. be nice to your family and respect is all what you should have for them..other then that it's really between you and Allah.

Comment: so he become a muslim right ?

Comment: absolutely  definitely yes